# Is there any possibility to set scale of multiple imageviews in a loop?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want to set the ScaleX and ScaleY of multiple imageviews to the same value.
Is there a possibility to do it in a loop?

```
for(int i=1;i<=9;i++){
String img = "imageview" + i;
(imageview + i).setScaleX(x);
}
// x is the variable
```

Comment: What do you want? Describe more detail

Comment: @Jasurbek I think the question describes perfectly what OP wants to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tested, but this should work

---

You could set a tag for each `ImageView`, making sure to increment each, for example:

```
//first ImageView
android:tag="@string/one" //one = 1
//second ImageView
android:tag="@string/two" //two = 2
```

Then in your for loop:

```
for(int i=1;i<=9;i++){ 
    ImageView img = findViewWithTag(String.valueOf(i)); 
    img.setScaleX(x); 
}
```

But I would not recommend this. Instead, just set the `setScaleX(x)` to each individually. It's not that much code.

Comment: I am using a little bit other programme now and it cannot be resolved by this
so I will do it manually I guess. Thanks anyway :D